# JQuery datepicker not updating hidden field on .blur

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm updating a hidden field, #start, with two fields: a text field (that is used for time) and a datepicker field. However, when I select a date using datepicker and there is nothing in the time field, the hidden field is not updated. Also when the time field is filled in and I select a date via datepicker, the date is updated with the previous selection rather than the most recently selected date (probably due to the input value being updated). How can I write this function correctly? Thank you!

```
$("#datepicker").blur(function () {
        var date = $(this).val();
        var time = $('#time').val();
        $("#start").val(date + time.toString(' HH:mm').toString());
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use .blur(), use the datepicker's [onSelect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) event.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/j4Lsm/)**

**jQuery**

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = $(this).val();
        var time = $('#time').val();
        $("#start").val(date + time.toString(' HH:mm').toString());
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add 'onSelect' event handler as well as 'blur' one.
See example [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89hWa/)

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({onSelect: populateHidden});
$("#datepicker").blur(populateHidden);


function populateHidden()
{
        var date = $("#datepicker").val();
        var time = $('#time').val();
        $("#start").val(date + ' ' + time);
}
```